# Sorting <li> list with programmatically added numbers to child elements

Tags: javascript, html

Searching for a solution to my problem, I have found many fixes for something **similar**, but not identical. However, since I would categorize myself as a javascript beginner, I can't figure out how to use those fixes for my own solution. Hence, I am asking you.

I am working on a chat. On one page there is a list of conversations. Each conversation look like this: `<li id="+conversationID+" class=\"people-item\"><a href=\"#\" id="+obj.newest_message_time+" class=\"list-group-item\"><span class="+conversationID+"><p class=\"participants\">" + participantsStringified + "</p><p class=\"new_message\">Me: "+obj.newest_message+"</p></span></a></li>;`

As you can see, the `<a>` inside `<li>` has an ID of `obj.newest_message_time`, which is a number that is programmatically added when the conversations is created.

So imaginging there are multiple `<li>`'s, how can I sort them by using the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a solution in the link below

https://jsfiddle.net/dwetouLf/

you can go ahead and change the value of the ID of anchor within LI to see if that works for you.

I am using the Jquery library foe this.

```
(function( $ ) {
$(function() {
    $( "li", "#test" ).sort(function( a, b ) {
        return $( a ).find('a').attr('id') > $(b).find('a').attr('id'); 
    }).appendTo( "#test" );
});

})( jQuery );
```